# Joint.js: Prevent a specific element to be linked

Tags: jointjs

I have a use case where I would like to create a diagram with joint.js, where some elements could be linked normally, but some shouldn't accept to or from links at all.

Is there some certain function or property that would allow this?

Comment: yes you can create any element and then set the magnet property to false to not link them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the `magnet:false` attribute e.g:

```
new joint.shapes.basic.Rect({
    position: { x: 50, y: 50 },
    size: { width: 300, height: 200 },
    attrs: {
        '.': { magnet: false }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.  It works great.  I'm wondering if you can explain "what it means".  For example, what does the key field of "." mean on the attrs object?  Why does a property of `magnet:false` not work?